# Hybris unable to login to HMC after MYSQL configuration

Tags: mysql, sap-commerce-cloud

I just configured Hybris for MYSQL and initialized the Hybris.

```
ant clean all
```

But when i try to login to HMC with http://10.22.1.168:9001/mcc/index.zul again, i get the below error:

[image]

have no mysql.log error, where are the possible issues?

But when i initialize ant i get.

[image]

and when i hit the mcc url i get:

[image]

Comment: Are you able to login to HAC (Admin Console)? If yes, did you try to initialize Hybris through Platform>Initialization option?

Comment: Yes i cud login to HAC and initialize, but during the process, i get the same filter chain exception in the console...this is happening only if i try to configure Hybris to use custom Database..in my case, i have configured for Mysql...If it uses, default HSQL, then ther is no issue... Also after using MYSQL, i get only around 215 tables in the backend...So where is the issue?

Comment: Have you done changes in local.properties or project.properties?
I hope you went through this link in Hybris Wiki for changing to custom database.
https://wiki.hybris.com/pages/viewpage.action?spaceKey=release5&title=Microsoft+SQL+Server

Comment: i have done in project.properties...no i dont have any resource for reference(for login to hybris wiki--i don ve SAP id )...could you please suggest how it can be done in local.prop for configuring MYSQL...

Comment: I guess you are using Mysql 5.7 ? If it's the case be aware that there is a bug in Hybris when it tries to create indices. use 5.6 instead or maria db (10.1.17 for example)

Comment: Regarding the bug @Benoit, when i initialize the ant there are around 282 tables populated in backend...post that when i initialized the Hybris server, it seems that the table count is gradually increasing to 283...may i know the total count of tables by default that Hybris provides

Comment: Well it really depends on your localextensions.xml

Comment: Depends on what? I just changed the values in the MYSQL configuration...is it possible to access the default Database tables in hybris?

Comment: On using my Mysql, when i start my hybri server, i get Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Table 'Hybris_testserver.props' doesn't exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please copy your custom database changes from project.properties to local.properties.
I'm using Oracle db and the setting for Oracle are as below:

```
db.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:XE
db.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
db.username=USER
db.password=password
db.tableprefix=
```

After these changes, kindly do *ant clean all* followed by *ant initialize*.

In case you still face issues, kindly check whether the Hybris version you're using is compatible with the version of MySQL.

**About your other question on how to configure multiple databases in Hybris:**

The detailed explanation is given at [Multi-Tenant Systems](https://wiki.hybris.com/pages/viewpage.action?spaceKey=release5&title=Multi-Tenant%20Systems)

Since you do not have a SAP ID, I'll briefly explain how it can be done.

Hybris can run in Multi-Tenant Mode, when using multiple tenants a hybris server instance can connect to multiple databases. Each tenant would represent a separate system with its own data source.

There are two kinds of tenant: **master** and **slave**.

Tenants need to be configured in the project.properties or local.properties file as below:

```
installed.tenants=junit,foo,t1,t2
```

Also, for each tenant, a properties file needs to be defined as *tenant_{tenantID}.properties*. The user can configure his own tenant properties files or override the current one, and the files must be put directly under the config directory, and the naming convention is *tenant_{tenantID}.properties*.

For example, the tenant_junit.properties file has the following properties:

```
cronjob.timertask.loadonstartup=false
db.factory=de.hybris.platform.jdbcwrapper.JUnitDataSourceFactory

db.tableprefix=junit_
alt.datasource.ALT1.foo=bar
alt.datasource.ALT2.foo=bar

slave.datasource.A.foo=bar
slave.datasource.B.foo=bar
slave.datasource.C.foo=bar

hmc.webroot=/hmc_junit
hac.webroot=/hac_junit

db.tableprefix=myjunit_
```

Include db details like url, username, password as well.

**Initialize the Master Tenant Before Initializing Slave Tenants**

Every tenant can have an individual set of active extensions selected from all extensions available on the hybris Commerce Suite.

```
allowed.extensions=core;processing;catalog;advancedsavedquery;comments;commons;deliveryzone;
forbidden.extensions=b2bapprovalprocess;b2bcommerce;basecommerce;btg;btgcockpit;payment;customerreview;
```

Comment: ok cool...how to configure hybris to use multiple DBs? say i have to instances of DB...sampleDB1 and sampleDB2...

Answer (score 2):

Hybris 5.7 is not compatible with MySQL 5.7

Comment: Does hybris-commerce-suite-5.3.0.3 support Mysql 5.7 ...?

Comment: Hybris 5.3 supports MySQL 5.5 and 5.6 versions only. From Hybris 6.x, MySQL 5.7 is supported.